# Creating Buttons Programmatically on Android

Tags: android, button, margin

I want to dynamically create 10 Buttons with Margin between each Button but things I tried won't work.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
//Create Button
for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
    MarginLayoutParams params = new MarginLayoutParams(MarginLayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, MarginLayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    params.setMargins(10, 0, 10, 0); 
    params.leftMargin = xpos;
    params.topMargin = ypos;
    params.width = 250;
    params.height = 150;    

    Button btn = new Button(this);
    btn.setId(i);
    final int _id = btn.getId();
    btn.setLayoutParams(params);
    btn.setText("Button " + _id);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Button clicked index =" + _id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            //Intent einauslagern = new Intent(v.getContext(), JockeyEinauslagern.class);
            //startActivityForResult(einauslagern, 0);
        }
    });
    xpos += 20;
    ypos += 50;
    this.addContentView(btn, params);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to get a container in your `Activity` class like this. (let it be `LinearLayout` for example).

Your XML -

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:orienation="vertical"
/>
```

Your Java -

```
LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams llp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(WRAP_CONTENT, WRAP_CONTENT);
//set your margins here
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Button button = new Button(this);
    // some stuff
    container.addView(button, llp);
}
```

With minor modifications this should work mostly fine.

Comment: I got another Problem now. Even after Deinstalling and clearing the chache, he is using my old code even when i completly removed him.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

// creates button
final Button btn = new Button(this);
btn.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
250,150));
btn.setPadding(0, 8, 0, 8); //or set margin if u need
btn.setTag(i);

yourContainserView.addView(channelBtn, i);
}
```